# Issue in setting values for a SOAP request in Apex

Tags: apex, soap-api, callout

I am working on SOAP call where the request is sent to Mulesoft, in order to build the request I'm trying to set the values first by querying the Sobject, after which I am assigning it to the wrapper object in the below code. For some reason I'm not able to get the value in the request xml for most of the attributes because they get nullified even if I hard code them, however I'm able to get some of the values. Strangely enough all the values appear in the debug log but some of them don't get passed to the request xml.

```
    if(lcf.Request_Type__c == 'Frequency Change'){
            String newFrequency = returnFrequencyMapping(lcf.New_Frequency__c);
            String currNextDueStringfc = lcf.Current_NextDue_Date__c.year() + '-' + lcf.Current_NextDue_Date__c.month() + '-' + lcf.Current_NextDue_Date__c.day();
            String newNextDueStringfc = lcf.New_NextDue_Date__c.year() + '-' + lcf.New_NextDue_Date__c.month() + '-' + lcf.New_NextDue_Date__c.day();
            Decimal currPay = lcf.Current_Payment_Amount__c==null?0.00:lcf.Current_Payment_Amount__c;
            WVClasses.UpdateLoanFreqRequest updateLoanFreqRequest = new WVClasses.UpdateLoanFreqRequest();
            updateLoanFreqRequest.CustomerNumber = lcf.loan__r.Customer_Number__r.AccountNumber; //Values from the query can be seen in xml
            updateLoanFreqRequest.LoanAccountNo = lcf.Loan__r.Name; //Values from the query can be seen in xml
            updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentFrequency = returnFrequencyMapping(lcf.Current_Frequency__c); //Values from the query can be seen in xml
            updateLoanFreqRequest.NewFrequency = newFrequency; //Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            
            updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentLPPbasecost = Decimal.valueOf(20);//Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentNextDue = currNextDueStringfc; //Values from the query can be seen in xml
            updateLoanFreqRequest.NewNextDue = newNextDueStringfc;//Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentPayment = currPay; //Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            updateLoanFreqRequest.NewLoanPayment = lcf.New_Payment_Amount__c==null?0.00:lcf.New_Payment_Amount__c; //Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentLPPbasecost = lcf.Current_LPP_Premium__c==null?0.00:lcf.Current_LPP_Premium__c; //Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentCObasecost = lcf.Current_Credit_Optimizer_payment__c==null?0.00:lcf.Current_Credit_Optimizer_payment__c; //Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            updateLoanFreqRequest.NewLPPPayment = lcf.New_LPP_Premium__c==null?0.00:lcf.New_LPP_Premium__c; //Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            updateLoanFreqRequest.NewCOAmount = lcf.New_Credit_Optimizer_payment__c==null?0.00:lcf.New_Credit_Optimizer_payment__c; //Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            updateLoanFreqRequest.NewDay1 = lcf.New_Day_1__c==null?'':lcf.New_Day_1__c;//Values hardcoded here get wiped out
            updateLoanFreqRequest.NewDay2 = lcf.New_Day2__c==null?'':lcf.New_Day2__c; //Values hardcoded here get wiped out
    
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.CustomerNumber: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.CustomerNumber);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.LoanAccountNo: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.LoanAccountNo);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentFrequency: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentFrequency);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.NewFrequency: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.NewFrequency);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentNextDue: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentNextDue);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.NewNextDue: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.NewNextDue);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentPayment: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentPayment);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.NewLoanPayment: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.NewLoanPayment);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentLPPbasecost: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentLPPbasecost);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentCObasecost: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentCObasecost);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.NewLPPPayment: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.NewLPPPayment);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.NewCOAmount: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.NewCOAmount);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.NewDay1: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.NewDay1);
            System.debug('updateLoanFreqRequest.NewDay2: ' + updateLoanFreqRequest.NewDay2);
            
            LoanManagement.UpdateLoanFreqResponse loanRespData = loanMgmt.updateLoanFreq(updateLoanFreqRequest);//response
            
            if(loanRespData.ErrorMessage !=null && loanRespData.ErrorMessage !=''){
                Loan_ChangeForm__c updateLoanChange = new Loan_ChangeForm__c();
                updateLoanChange.Id = lcf.Id;
                updateLoanChange.Error_Message__c = loanRespData.ErrorMessage;
                updateLoanChange.Loan_Form_Status_c__c = 'Cancelled - Fail';
                update updateLoanChange;
            }
            else{
                Loan_ChangeForm__c updateLoanChange = new Loan_ChangeForm__c();
                updateLoanChange.Id = lcf.Id;
                updateLoanChange.Loan_Form_Status_c__c = 'Actioned';
                update updateLoanChange;
            }
        }
        
        Below is the wrapper for WVClasses.UpdateLoanFreqRequest
        public class UpdateLoanFreqRequest {
            public Decimal CurrentCObasecost=146.92; // hardcoding here pushes the value to the xml request but that defeats the purpose
            public String CurrentFrequency;
            public Decimal CurrentLPPbasecost;
            public String CurrentNextDue;
            public Decimal CurrentPayment;
            public String CustomerNumber;
            public String LoanAccountNo;
            public Decimal NewCOAmount;
            public String NewDay1;
            public String NewDay2;
            public String NewFrequency;
            public Decimal NewLPPPayment;
            public Decimal NewLoanPayment;
            public String NewNextDue;
            private String[] CurrentCObasecost_type_info = new String[]{'CurrentCObasecost','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] CurrentFrequency_type_info = new String[]{'CurrentFrequency','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] CurrentLPPbasecost_type_info = new String[]{'CurrentLPPbasecost','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] CurrentNextDue_type_info = new String[]{'CurrentNextDue','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] CurrentPayment_type_info = new String[]{'CurrentPayment','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] CustomerNumber_type_info = new String[]{'CustomerNumber','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','true'};
            private String[] LoanAccountNo_type_info = new String[]{'LoanAccountNo','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','true'};
            private String[] NewCOAmount_type_info = new String[]{'NewCOAmount','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] NewDay1_type_info = new String[]{'NewDay1','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','true'};
            private String[] NewDay2_type_info = new String[]{'NewDay2','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','true'};
            private String[] NewFrequency_type_info = new String[]{'NewFrequency','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] NewLPPPayment_type_info = new String[]{'NewLPPPayment','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] NewLoanPayment_type_info = new String[]{'NewLoanPayment','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] NewNextDue_type_info = new String[]{'NewNextDue','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents',null,'1','1','false'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EFSWebSrvs.Documents','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'CurrentCObasecost','CurrentFrequency','CurrentLPPbasecost','CurrentNextDue','CurrentPayment','CustomerNumber','LoanAccountNo','NewCOAmount','NewDay1','NewDay2','NewFrequency','NewLPPPayment','NewLoanPayment','NewNextDue'};
    }
```

Comment: Is there any other automation in place that's overwriting the hardcoded values? Are you running it under the same user? Could be a Field Level Security issue.

Comment: Yes, im running it as the same user and there's no automation in place. Even hardcoding values for ex: updateLoanFreqRequest.CurrentLPPbasecost = Decimal.valueOf(20); will not set it. but will appear as null in the request.

Comment: Is WVClasses.UpdateLoanFreqRequest the class that was generated when you imported the WSDL, or is that something that you created? Also, does the debug and sending of the request happen in the same transaction, or are you debugging it separately (test class or anonymous console)?

Comment: It was generated by the WSDL and the debugging and sending of request happens in the same transaction, what I realized later after putting advanced logs is that there's another class which takes the wrapper as an input and gets reinitialized, but in that class not all attributes have been mentioned which explains why these fields are getting nullified.